# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms

I'm trying to take input of a domain name (`domainNm`) and an email address at a domain (`emailVerified`) and submit them via `modelform` based off a table [`Tld`] .

It appears, it is failing to `save()` the foreign key (from the currently authenticated user)

```
domain.FKtoClient = user_info
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**forms.py**

```
class SubmitDomain(ModelForm):
    domainNm = forms.CharField(initial=u'', label='Enter your domain')
    emailVerified = forms.EmailField(label='Email at Domain')

    class Meta:
        model = Tld #Create form based off Model for Tld
        fields = ['domainNm','emailVerified']

    def save(self, request=None):
        instance = self.cleaned_data
        #domain =  instance["domainNm"])
        domains = Tld.objects.filter(domainNm=instance["domainNm"])
        if len(domains) == 0:
            domain = Tld()
        else:
            domain = domains[0]
        user_info = request.user
        unique_id = int(uuid.uuid4())
        domain.generated_hash = str(unique_id)
        domain.entered_email = instance["emailVerified"]
        domain.domainNm = instance["domainNm"]
        domain.FKtoClient = user_info
        domain.save()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please include the *full* traceback of the exception. You failed to include even the exception message; you are asking us to take stabs in the dark here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def save(self, request=None):
```

You assign a default value of `None` to `request` in the definition of `save`, so what happens when the caller of `save` doesn't pass an instantiated request?

```
user_info = request.user #request is None here
```

That will throw the error you see. To mitigate, add a simple `if request is not None` or similar statement.

**EDIT**

After seeing your `views.py`, you are passing `request.POST` to `SubmitDomain`'s `__init__` magic method, which you have not defined. The way you have your modelform defined above, you would have to pass the request to `save()`, not `__init__()`, i.e.

```
form.save(request)
```

Comment: Should I just remove the request=None in the def save() ?

Comment: Requests will typically be handled via your `views.py`. What are you intending this save to do for your models?

Comment: It will save a record of the information inputted in the form to the db

Comment: Would probably need to see the code where you call `.save()` on your custom `ModelForm`. If you want to get the user you would need to pass in the request.

Comment: Do you see the last line above domain.save() ?

Comment: Yes, but that's not where you are getting this error. YOu can never get the user_info because (I am assuming) you never pass the request when you call `.save()` on the `ModelForm` in your `views.py`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50705/discussion-between-c-b-and-codetalk)

Comment: Let's chat on the discussion